# How to convert a column to an array of column values using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My SQL query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT
  users.username,
  users.email,
  json_build_object('bookId', votes.book_id, 'vote', votes.vote) AS "booksVote"
FROM users
LEFT JOIN votes
ON users.id = votes.user_id
WHERE users.id='1'
```

This query currently returns:

```
[
  {
     "username": "Bret",
     "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
     "booksVote": { "bookId": "1", "vote": "4" }
  },
  {
     "username": "Bret",
     "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
     "booksVote": { "bookId": "2", "vote": null }
  }
]
```

But I want the query to return:

```
{
   "username": "Bret",
   "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
   "booksVote": [
      { "bookId": "1", "vote": "4" },
      { "bookId": "2", "vote": null }
   ]
}
```

Please help me to make a query that will return for a given user the combined column "booksVote" which will be an array of all column values.

Comment: `SELECT json_build_object(
    'mail', users.username,
    'name', users.email,

    'votes', array_agg(json_build_object(
        'bookId', votes.book_id,
        'vote', votes.vote
                              )))
FROM users
         LEFT JOIN votes
                   ON users.id = votes.user_id
WHERE users.id='1'
GROUP BY users.email`.